# Java polymorphism and lists

Tags: java, list, polymorphism, extends

Say I have the following class structure

```
public abstract class MyClass{}

public class MyClassA extends MyClass{}

public class MyClassB extends MyClass{}
```

How do I create a list of MyClass elements that contains both MyClassA and MyClassB elements without objections?

e.g.

```
    List<MyClass> myList = new LinkedList<MyClassA>();
```

Comment: `List<MyClass> list = ...// pick your favorite`.

Comment: It does not like that, I get an error "Required List<MyClass> but found List<MyClassA>"

Comment: List<? extends MyClass> also works.

Comment: A `List<MyClassA>` cannot work with `MyClassB` or `MyClass` objects so what you are doing is wrong. We could further explain it if you showed us.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, that really helped, want to put it as the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on your needs you have several options. You can either use plain `List<MyClass>` type objects. This allows you to add objects of types `MyClassA` and `MyClassB`. You can't set a List type object to a variable whose type is `List<MyClass>`. This is due to a concept called **variance**. Three types of variance exist in most programming languages that support generics (parametrized polymofism).

### Invariance

Invariance *does not allow one to deviate from a type* in either direction. This is the case with generics in Java by default and that's why you can't assign a `List<MyClassA>` to a variable of `List<MyClass>`.
Imagine the following scenario:

```
List<MyClassA> listA = new List<MyClassA>();
List<MyClass> list = (List<MyClass>) listA; // Produces a compilation error...
list.add(new MyClassB()); // ... because this would be a big no-no
```

### Covariance

Covariance *allows you to use a the designated parameter type or any subtype thereof*. In Java, you use the extends keyword to designate covariance: `List<? extends MyClass>`. It is allowed to assign a List type object into such a variable. With covariance, however, you can not add any objects to your generic object instance without an explicit cast. That is you can not do the following:

```
List<? extends MyClass> list = new LinkedList<MyClassA>();
list.add(new MyClassA());
```

This is only logical. After all, you can not know exactly what type of a List you are dealing with. It might as well be a `List<MyClassB>`.

### Contravariance

Contravariance is *the opposite of covariance* and is designated using the super keyword: `List<? super MyClassA>`. It is allowed to assign a `List<MyClass>` (but not a `List<MyClassB>`) type object into such a variable. With contravariance you can add any subtype of the designated type parameter (lower limit in the type hierarchy). That is, it's allowed to do the following:

```
List<? super MyClass> list = new LinkedList<MyClass>();
list.add(new ChildA());
```

You can not, however, know exactly what type of a List the object is. That is you can only direclty assign an object stored in the list into a variable of type Object without an explicit cast:

```
Object o = list.get(0);
if (o instanceof MyClassA) {
  MyClassA mca = (MyClassA) o;
  //...
}
```

I hope this helps to clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism is the ability of an object to take on many forms. The most common use of polymorphism in OOP occurs when a parent class reference is used to refer to a child class object. A parent class reference can hold the objects of any of its subclasses. So a collection of a parent can hold the child classes objects. For example:

```
 List<MyClass> myClassList = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcards like `List<? extends MyClass> myList = new ArrayList<MyClassA>();` but that will only let you get items from the list. Adding items is not safe since you can't know what's the underlying type of the `List`. You will have to add your items to the actual instance of your list directly like:

```
List<? extends MyClass> myList = null;

ArrayList<MyClassA> actualListA = new ArrayList<MyClassA>();
myList = actualListA;
MyClassA myClassA = new MyClassA();
actualListA.add(myClassA);
myList.add(new MyClassA()); //Nope, you can't do this because myList could be assigned to an array of MyClassB items like the following.

//Reassign
ArrayList<MyClassB> actualListB = new ArrayList<MyClassB>();
myList = actualListB;
MyClassB myClassB = new MyClassB();
actualListB.add(myClassB);

//Get item
MyClass item = myList.get(0);// This will give you the myClassB object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `List` interface to implement your concrete/abstract classes. Something like this.

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Covariance**
Covariance allows you to use a the designated parameter type or any subtype thereof. In Java, you use the extends keyword to designate covariance: List<? extends MyClass>.

This works for me as a type cast for a list